# Flutter error: Could not load wrapper properties from /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-test

i am new to flutter, i just followed an online video on setting up flutter on my MacBook pro and i just created my first project and tried to run it while my system is connected to the internet  but got this error bellow

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load wrapper properties from '/Users/bright/AndroidStudioProjects/second_flutterapp/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties'.
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forWrapperPropertiesFile(WrapperExecutor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:60)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 62: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-all.zip to gradle-6.7-all.zip
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrl(WrapperExecutor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.prepareDistributionUri(WrapperExecutor.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:57)
    ... 2 more
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i have see many issues like this with answers here but non fixed my issue... i have tried deleting "gradle-wrapper.jar" and Replacing "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-all.zip to gradle-6.4.1-all.zip" on the gradle-wrapper-properties file and running the comman "flutter run" on my terminal but still get same error

i have tried "flutter doctor" which gave me the result down bellow

```
Brights-MBP:~ bright$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021 darwin-x64,
    locale en-NG)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
      development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

i know i have not installed Xcode which i will do later but am not sure if thats the issue
#what am i doing wrong?

Comment: i have found the error... when i copied the new distribution link i copied it with some errors... instead of distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip..... i copied and pasted (https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-all.zip to gradle-6.7-all.zip) when i changed it everything started working

Comment: In my case it was an extra space added after the gradle URL :), Removed it and fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the path, the error clearly stated that:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 62: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-all.zip to gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

When checking the file ***gradle-x.x.x-all.zip*** in [services.gradle.org/ distributions/](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/), it is not existing while the ***gradle-6.7-all.zip*** was found. So it could be a big factor that there was an error copying the distributions path. The proper file should be ***gradle-6.7-all.zip***.

Also, you've mentioned that this was the first time Flutter was setup in your MacOS. With this, you can always check the guide from the Flutter documentation about [macOS install](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#macos-setup) for any missed steps/processes.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows your characters in "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-xxx-all.zip to gradle-6.4.1-all.zip"

Just change it to something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4DvR.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32921035)